# Use Bearer token in external OAuth authentication provider in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, oauth, bearer-token

Here is `Startup.cs` from [SignInWithAppleSample](https://github.com/martincostello/SignInWithAppleSample):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services
        .AddAuthentication(options => options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/signin";
            options.LogoutPath = "/signout";
        })
        .AddApple(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["AppleClientId"];
            options.KeyId = Configuration["AppleKeyId"];
            options.TeamId = Configuration["AppleTeamId"];

            options.UsePrivateKey(
                (keyId) =>
                    Environment.ContentRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo($"AuthKey_{keyId}.p8"));
        });

    // ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // ...

    app.UseAuthentication();

    // ...
}
```

Here's controller's method, which uses for authentication:

```
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("~/signin")]
    public IActionResult SignIn()
        => Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/redirect/signin/apple" }, AppleAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    [HttpGet("~/signout")]
    [HttpPost("~/signout")]
    public IActionResult SignOut()
        => SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/redirect/signout/apple" }, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

It works, cookies set, I can see my claims.

In my project, I don't use built-in ASP.NET Core, I simply need to handle request on `/redirect/signin/apple` and return access token, identity token, etc. to my clients, and maybe check in DB that this user is already registered. Client's don't want cookies, they accept only Bearer tokens.

So, the question is, how can I get Bearer token instead of cookies?

Comment: you can use identity server for this Below link could help

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html

Comment: @Workaholic due to internal reasons, I can't use any external libraries such as IdentityServer4, only Microsoft's provided.

Comment: It is not Microsoft provided but it is Microsoft's recommended. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/secure-net-microservices-web-applications/

Comment: @Workaholic unfortunately internal reasons forbid to use it. Are there any other possibilities?